# Can I fill an args[] param dinamically on java?

Tags: java, arrays, parameters, runtime

I need some recommendation about this code I have in Java8.

I have this method:

```
public Object method (String objectName, List<ParamData> paramsList)
```

`paramList` can have one or more objects inside, then I call the invoke method of an object of the Method class.

```
// params must be the objects that paramList have
object = find.invoke(class, params);
```

The invoke method can receive one or more params and I want to send it the objects that I have in the parameter `paramList`, but each time can be a different number of them, and a different method instance, that can receive one parameter, two... and I don't know if there is some way to fill these params at runtime, but not being an array.

I will appreciate any help you can give me.

Thank you a lot.

I only try to send it a list of this params objects that obviously didn't work, the other ideas I had I realized at the moment that they will not work.

Answer (score 1):

In the `Method` class, `invoke()` is defined as :

```
public Object invoke(Object obj, Object... args)
```

So all you need is converting the `List` that you manipulate to an array : [`List.toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-) does that.
Then pass it to `invoke()` such as :

```
public Object method (String objectName, List<ParamData> paramsList){
   ParamData[] params = paramsList.toArray(new ParamData(paramsList.size()));
   // ...
   Method method = ...
   method.invoke(obj, params);
}
```

As a side note, that is a way to fill an array dynamically : from a source (the list) to the array but you have other ways to fill an array dynamically with some objects such as [`Arrays.fill(Object[] a, Object val)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-). The difference here is that it fills the array elements with the same object reference: `val`. That is not your requirement : you want to fill from a source of data (the list).

Comment: Hi! excuse me, i this i did not explain the situation well, is a little more complicated, i will edit the post with more info, the invoke method recibe an array of objects, but the method that it call itself not, in fact, in each execution, the Method instance can be diferent and some of then recibe only one param, some recieve two... not one method with "one or more "so it doesn´t work in this case.

But thanks you any case, i learned one more thing.

Comment: oh! excuse me again, it works, i forget one thing more that i need to do, thank you so much! ^^